# Select only specific attributes in a list[classType]?

Tags: scala, list, scala-collections, case-class

I am trying to select specific attributes in a list of case class type. Let me explain

This is my test.txt file:

```
india|M|IND|P|15951124869|15
usa|F|usa|R|15951178869|25
australia|M|aus|S|15951189869|35
kenya|M|KN|F|15956624869|55
russia|M|rus|u|15981124869|75
china|T|ch|L|15951128869|95
england|F|eng|Z|15959124869|65
germany|F|ger|I|15987124869|25
finland|M|fin|H|15967124869|45
singapore|F|sing|I|15956124869|65
```

Case class:

```
case class Deshi(country: String, gender: String, countryCode: String, statusJi: String, gadiNumber: String, age: String)
defined class Deshi
```

Reading test.txt file:

```
scala> val deshiLines=readFileC("/Users/neha.gambhir/Desktop/test.txt")
deshiLines: List[String] = List(india|M|IND|P|15951124869|15, usa|F|usa|R|15951178869|25, australia|M|aus|S|15951189869|35, kenya|M|KN|F|15956624869|55, russia|M|rus|u|15981124869|75, china|T|ch|L|15951128869|95, england|F|eng|Z|15959124869|65, germany|F|ger|I|15987124869|25, finland|M|fin|H|15967124869|45, singapore|F|sing|I|15956124869|65)
```

This is my list of case class type:

```
scala> val nayaDeshiList=deshiLines.map{  raw_line => 
     |             val columns = raw_line.split("\\|")
     |  Deshi(columns(0), columns(1), columns(2), columns(3), columns(4), columns(5))
     |  } 
nayaDeshiList: List[Deshi] = List(Deshi(india,M,IND,P,15951124869,15), Deshi(usa,F,usa,R,15951178869,25), Deshi(australia,M,aus,S,15951189869,35), Deshi(kenya,M,KN,F,15956624869,55), Deshi(russia,M,rus,u,15981124869,75), Deshi(china,T,ch,L,15951128869,95), Deshi(england,F,eng,Z,15959124869,65), Deshi(germany,F,ger,I,15987124869,25), Deshi(finland,M,fin,H,15967124869,45), Deshi(singapore,F,sing,I,15956124869,65))
```

I want to only select `country, gender, age` from the above `nayaDeshiList`. Since this `nayaDeshiList` type is of case class `Deshi` so I did `nayaDeshiList.type`, `nayaDeshiList.country` which is not working for me. Can somebody suggest me a better approach?

**Note:** I am only interested in solving this using pure Scala way not on any computation engine like Spark

**Output:** output should retain the class type. For instance, it should still have the same type, like this `nayaDeshiList: List[Deshi]`. The only difference is it should contain only specific columns as mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
nayaDeshiList.map(x => (x.country, x.gender, x.age))
```

The result is a `List((String,String,String))`. You don't state how you want the data elements organized. I put them in a tuple, but there are other options.

Comment: thanks @jwvh I want to perform computation (aggregate operations) like we do on table in database, can you provide me link for other options or please update the answer if possible.

Comment: @Button Monkey  pls clearly explain what exactly you want to do when you aggregate ? I feel the above answer is the valid one for your question. else please update your question...

Comment: I need to only find duplicate records after selecting these fields. My definition of duplicate record is, if country and age are same, it's a duplicate record. I have to store all these duplicate records and finally perform a groupBy operation based on `country` field @BDR

Comment: @jwvh thank you for your answer, this output is giving me a tuple of string type, can I have output with the same `Deshi` case class type but with only 3 column names? finally I want to perform a `groupBy()` operation on groupBy("country","age")......

Comment: @ButtonMonkey; There are a few reasons why your question isn't getting many responses. 1-The original question was rather vague. I took a guess at what I thought you wanted. 2-By the time you updated the question it was already a bit old and many SO readers don't notice older questions, even after they've been updated. 3-The updated question is only slightly related to the original question. It deserves to be its own (new) question where it will get more attention and answers. 4-The updated question is still a bit vague. Adding expected output for the sample input would help clarify it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jwvh I updated a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741714/fetch-all-the-duplicate-records-from-a-list-without-quadratic-time-complexity

please check this question above