# Fetch all the duplicate records from a list without quadratic time complexity?

Tags: scala, performance, time-complexity, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

Below is my list which contains the column names: country, gender & age.

```
scala> funList
res1: List[(String, String, String)] = List((india,M,15), (usa,F,25), (australia,M,35), (kenya,M,55), (russia,M,75), (china,T,95), (england,F,65), (germany,F,25), (finland,M,45), (australia,F,35))
```

My goal is to find the duplicate records with the combination of (country,age). Please note that I want to only fetch all the duplicate records and ignore others. And list should also contain other column values with the duplicate records.

Output should be like this:

```
australia,M,35
australia,F,35
```

It would be nice if you do without groupBy operation and without n*square complexity. GroupBy is fine unless it messes up my output.

Comment: `groupBy {_ == _} filter {_.count > 1}` comes to mind.

Comment: I don't think the above groupBy operation works

Comment: You're right. `xs groupBy { x => x } filter { case (x, y) => y.length > 2 }` works though.

Comment: No, you're grouping by the whole tuple, Button Monkey only wants duplicates by two items in the tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `groupBy()`. Not sure about the complexity.

```
val keys = funList.map{case (a,b,c) => (a,c)}  //isolate elements of interest
val dups = keys diff keys.distinct             //find the duplicates
funList.filter{case (a,b,c) => dups.contains((a,c))}
//res0: List[(String, String, String)] = List((australia,M,35), (australia,F,35))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of what you mean by `groupBy`'s possibility to mess with the output. You can use it as follows and you'll get back the list of duplicates you're looking for:

```
// input
val items = List(("india","M",15), ("usa","F",25), ("australia","M",35), ("kenya","M",55), ("russia","M",75), ("china","T",95), ("england","F",65), ("germany","F",25), ("finland","M",45), ("australia","F",35))

items.
  groupBy { case (nation, _, age) => nation -> age }. // group by relevant items
  filter(_._2.length > 1).                            // keep only duplicates
  flatMap(_._2)                                       // get them and flatten the result
```

**Alternatively** you may be interested in using `groupBy` as the basis for your own function that buckets values by a key and filter the result by some predicate, like the following:

```
implicit class FilterGroups[A, CC[X] <: Iterable[X]](self: CC[A]) {
  import scala.collection.mutable
  import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
  import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
  def filterGroups[K, That](f: A => K)(p: CC[A] => Boolean)(implicit bfs: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], A, CC[A]], bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[A], A, That]): That = {
    val m = mutable.Map.empty[K, Builder[A, CC[A]]]
    for (elem <- self) {
      val key = f(elem)
      val bldr = m.getOrElseUpdate(key, bfs())
      bldr += elem
    }
    val b = bf()
    for {
      (_, v) <- m
      group = v.result if p(group)
      elem <- group
    } b += elem
    b.result
  }
}
```

You'd then invoke it as follows:

```
// bucket by the first function, filter by the second one
items.filterGroups(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._3))(_.length > 1)
```

And, just as above, get back the desired list of items:

```
List((australia,M,35), (australia,F,35))
```

The only main advantage of the alternative solution is that the output type is the same as the input, while using `groupBy` forces your result type to be an `Iterable[(String, String, Int)]`. Not sure if you maybe meant this by *messing up the output*.

Either way, I'd say the time complexity is effectively linear (we have to make one pass to bucket and one to filter, but still we can get rid of constants in big-O notation). This of course means that space complexity is bound to the collection size as well (since we bucket the original results).

One final note: you may want to not use lists when you are measuring size, as its complexity is linear. Both my solution and the one using `groupBy` use builders of the same type of the original collection, so you may want to use a `Vector` or some other collection with *O(1)* for computing `length`.

But **the right answer is probably to just use `groupBy`**, which is simpler and clear to any other Scala developer (although you probably also want to use a lazy view through the iteration to prevent unnecessary double passes over the data).

Comment: BTW, for measuring length of lists, there's `lengthCompare` method

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this.